# Updating array of objects with timestamps

Tags: arrays, object

I have a data structure like this :

```
var records = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    id: "0543236543",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    id: "0994372684",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    id: "0487345643",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    id: "04873452342",
  },
];
```

I want to create a function that would add the date property (adjusted for hours) to each of object in the array depending on the length of the array.

Here's my code so far

```
function updateObject(obj) {
  let timeNow = new Date();
  let addHours = (h) => timeNow.setHours(timeNow.getHours() + h);
  const ids = obj.map((record) => record.id);
  const lastNames = obj.map((record) => record.id);
  const time = obj.map(
    (record, index) => (record["time"] = new Date(addHours(index)))
  );
  return obj;
}
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    firstName: 'Akira',
    id: '0543236543',
    time: 2021-05-18T12:25:59.366Z
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Harry',
    id: '0994372684',
    time: 2021-05-18T13:25:59.366Z
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Sherlock',
    id: '0487345643',
    time: 2021-05-18T15:25:59.366Z
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Kristian',
    id: '04873452342',
    time: 2021-05-18T18:25:59.366Z
  }
]
```

First issue: I want to update the time by adding 0,1,2,3 hours to the current time.
Currently it:
adds 0 to time and sets is a current time
adds 1 to updated time and set it a as a current time and so on.

Second:
I want to modify the function so it takes an add additional argument, "time increment" that if set to x will update the time property for first x records for 0 hours and the next x records for 1 hour.

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

First issue can be solved by changing `addHours` to be a pure function that does not mutate `timeNow`:

```
const timeNow = Date.now();
const addHours = (h) => new Date(timeNow + h * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Second issue can be solved by looking at the index in the map:

```
const time = obj.map(
(record, index) => (record["time"] = new Date(addHours(index > increment ? 1 : 0))));
```

And in general, I would advise against mutating objects/arrays. Pure functions are usually easier to reason about and offer fewer surprises.
I would write the `updateObject` function so it does not mutate the original, but returns a new array with new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! What if the *increment* parameter defines how many first x records should have the time property increased by 1h
For example my contacts array length is 4.

```
function updateObject(records, 1) {
  \\code here
}
```

The first object would have the time property increased by 0h.
The second object would have the time property increased by 1h.
The third object would have the time property increased by 2h.
The fourth object would have the time property increased by 3h.

```
function updateObject(records, 3) {
  \\code here
}
```

The first 3 objects would have the time property increased by 0h.
The fourth object would have the time property increased by 1h.

Do I need to slice the array into sub arrays first?